# Hovering over 1 div to change content in another

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I posted this last week and tried everything but still cant get it working. I will post a link to my code pen (images aren't loaded in so you wont see it but you can check out the code and see what I've messed up) 
 In the end I am trying to hover over #market and it change the content in colc (or any col for that matter) to a different image. in the head you will see my attempt but it isnt working. Thank you for any help you can provide. :)

https://codepen.io/callum-mcleod/pen/rRwRmm

```
    <script>

$('#market').hover(function () {
  $('#colc').css('content', 'url("_img/images/blue3.png")');
});
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: please add the relevant code and not a link to a pen that doesn't do anything

Comment: How do i add the code with all the images with it? I tried linking but it didnt seem to be working

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have 2 rows of 3 Elements. I want to hover over one of the bottom elements and it changes the image in all 3 of the top row

Comment: You want to set background image using js. what elements do you want to set background-image?

Comment: Currently the 3 top divs (#cola #colb and #colc) are empty in the css and just have a "content: url()" with a local image. The static image goes fine but I'm having trouble changing that "content:url()" when hoving over the 2nd row of divs (#graphic, #web and # market)

Comment: See #market does not have any content to display so Hover on that doesn't make any sence

Comment: #market currently also has its own "content:url()" but this is working fine and I don't need this one to change. Also thank you very much for your patience I am a bit slow with this stuff

Comment: Ok i worked on my own you are doing correctly. but your hove is not working 

<script>
  $(document).on('mouseover','#market',function () {
   $('#colc').css("content", "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/459225/pexels-photo-459225.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=100&w=940')");
  })
 </script>

Comment: are you wanting to change all three divs (cola,b,c) to the same image when you hover over `#market` ?

Comment: I want them to change to all different images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML layout, as taken from the linked to codepen snippet:

```
<div class='rowmonitor'>
    <div id='cola'></div>
    <div id='colb'></div>
    <div id='colc'></div>   
</div>
<div class='rowblock'>
    <a href='graphic.html'>
        <div id='graphic'></div>
    </a>
    <a href='web.html'>
        <div id='web'></div>
    </a>
    <a href='market.html'>
        <div id='market'></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

In the CSS of the `pen` you have

```
#market:hover ~ #colc
```

As you found out, this selector will not work for the structure of HTML that you have. There is no `previous sibling` type selector - `~` is for accessing the following element. To accomplish the switching of background images ( weirdly using the `content` attribute rather than `background-image` ) you'd need to resort to javascript of some flavour or other. The following demo uses vanilla javascript and might, or might not, offer help - should be easy to modify to use your images rather than images from the interwebs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Change DIV element content on hover over another element</title>
        <style>
            body *{display:block;box-sizing:border-box;}
            .rowmonitor,
            .rowblock{width:50%;float:left;clear:none;margin:0;padding:0;}

            .rowmonitor > div,
            .rowblock > a{width:33%;float:none;clear:none;margin:1rem; padding:0.25rem;}


            .rowblock > a > div{padding:1rem;width:100%;height:3rem;}

            /* randomly selected source images */
            #cola{content:url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/24/fd/a5/24fda5fb3317da38db13209cfd2651b9.gif)}
            #colb{content:url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0094/5691/0395/t/5/assets/LOGO_belif_200_50_800x800.png?15542124892649134758);}
            #colc{content:url(https://mosaic01.ztat.net/nvg/media/brandxl/3ea6e361-fada-43bd-9a28-368f176e6dcd.jpg);}

            /* more randomly selected background images */
            #graphic{background:url(https://www.micahjtphotos.com/img/s/v-2/p3109013942-11.jpg)}
            #web{background:url(https://www.countryside-trust.org.uk/userfiles/events/images/blue_moon_-_cockington_middle_lake_1.jpg?w=200&h=100&zc=1)}
            #market{background:url(https://www.tbhpartnership.org.uk/content/uploads/2016/09/EnglemerePond-200x100.jpg)}

            .rowblock > a > div{background-size:100%!important;background-repeat:no-repeat!important;background-position:center}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{

                let matrix={
                    cola:{
                        over:'https://i2.wp.com/www.sphk.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/the-river.jpg?fit=300%2C100&ssl=1',
                        out:''
                    },
                    colb:{
                        over:'https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/rendered/search/poster/images-medium-5/karst-landscape-along-the-river-li-panoramic-images.jpg',
                        out:''
                    },
                    colc:{
                        over:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsFI7Ra8KNFWCAr_kEXEkrK9Z1hYOK0Hm8WVNno7b5X3glATzo',
                        out:''
                    }
                };

                /* get reference to the targets whose background will be changed */
                let cols=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('.rowmonitor > div') );

                /* further populate matrix with initial content images */
                cols.forEach( function( div ){
                    /* this will store: url( https://www.example.com/img.jpg ) */
                    matrix[ this.id ]=getComputedStyle( div ).content;
                })

                /* assign event listeners to each source rowblock > a element */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('.rowblock > a') ).forEach( a => {

                    /* change the images on rollover */
                    a.addEventListener( 'mouseover', evt=>{
                        cols.forEach( div=>{
                            /* explicitly set the url property */
                            div.style.content='url(' + matrix[ div.id ].over + ')';
                        });
                    });

                    /* restore the images on rollout */
                    a.addEventListener( 'mouseout', evt=>{
                        cols.forEach( div=>{
                            /* as we stored the url property can set directly */
                            div.style.content=matrix[ div.id ].out;
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- other html content -->


        <div class='rowmonitor'>
            <div id='cola'></div>
            <div id='colb'></div>
            <div id='colc'></div>   
        </div>
        <div class='rowblock'>
            <a href='graphic.html'>
                <div id='graphic'></div>
            </a>
            <a href='web.html'>
                <div id='web'></div>
            </a>
            <a href='market.html'>
                <div id='market'></div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- more html content -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jQuery.

```
var imageUrl = "_img/images/blue3.png";
$("#market,#graphic,#web").on("hover",function(){
  $('#colc,#colb,#cola').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not about JS or Jquery. Firstly, `content: url("_img/images/blue1.png");` is blocking any content from showing up in `colc` div. Then, you should add some content for it to be displayable or explicitly set the width and the height of the element.
And the final notes: probably, it is better to use `background` property to set background image rather than `content`
PS Links should be valid too

Comment: Okay thank you, I am trying this but when I use background:image the image is invisible unless I put something in the div in the html (like text or I even got it working with a transparent png the same size) How can I get background-image working (I tried changing height an width to px and vh and still no difference)